# Cannot bookmark pages in Firefox

Tags: windows-10, firefox, bookmarks

I have Firefox ESR 60.8 on Windows 10. In the bookmarks toolbar, I see some bookmarks that were synchronized from another computer through my Firefox web account. But, I cannot make any changes to my bookmarks:

- I cannot bookmark new pages. Clicking the "bookmark" star does nothing - the star remains white instead of becoming yellow as it should.
- I cannot even move bookmarks in the existing bookmark toolbar.
- When I change bookmarks in the other computer, the changes do not synchronize to this computer.

What I tried:

- Refresh Firefox;
- Start in safe mode;
- Delete the file "xulstore.json" in the profile folder.

None of these helped. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have any extensions for toolbars or bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be lacking permissions on the file `places.sqlite` that is found
in the profile folder at `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\your-profile`.
Check that you have full control of the file by, in Explorer,
doing right-click, select Properties, and look in the Security tab.

If this doesn't help, try to
[start Firefox in Safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode).
If bookmarks then work, then some add-on is blocking them.
Disable add-ons one-by-one until you find the cause.

If both the above didn't help, then `places.sqlite` might be corrupted.
Export all your bookmarks to a file, close Firefox and move
`places.sqlite` out of the profile folder. Restart Firefox and it will create
automatically a new and empty `places.sqlite`.
You can now import the saved bookmarks back.

If none of the above helped, Firefox itself may be corrupted.
Do a clean re-install by uninstalling Firefox using
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/),
then searching the disk and deleting any folder whose name contains the
string "Mozilla", finally installing Firefox again.
Save first any file you wish to keep.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and I have full control of this file. Safe mode I already tried and it did not help. If I do not find another solution, I will try to reinstall..

Comment: When reinstalling, you might save `places.sqlite` and try to reuse it, but keep the empty new one in case the database-file itself is corrupted and you will need it to restart from scratch. For this worst scenario, better also backup the bookmarks in another format. Alternatively, you might just save bookmarks, replace `places.sqlite` with an empty one, then import, all without reinstalling Firefox.

Comment: How do I create an empty places.sqlite file?

Comment: Delete "places.sqlite" with Firefox closed, then restart it. A new and empty file should be created automatically.

Comment: This solved the problem! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad that it helped. I incorporated our comments into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your changes to your bookmarks do not appear when you restart Firefox, the issue may be that your bookmarks file is write-protected. A write-protected file can't be changed, which prevents Firefox from saving any changes you have made.

Allow Firefox to save bookmark changes:

Open your profile folder:

Click the menu button  Fx57menu , click Help and select Troubleshooting Information. The Troubleshooting Information tab will open.

Under the Application Basics section, click on Open Folder. Your profile folder will open.

Close Firefox completely:
Click the Firefox menu  Fx57Menu , then click Exit.
Right-click the file places.sqlite, and select Properties to open the Properties window.
In the Properties window, select the General tab. Near the bottom of the window, verify that Read-only is NOT selected.

From: [support.mozilla.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Bookmarks_not_saved)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. Read-Only is not selected, but bookmark still does not work..